# run OPCTest status automatically

Tags: vba, cmd

currently, I need to perform two manual tasks:

Task 1) run opctest.exe /cust customer /node node_name
Task 2) run status

Currently, opctest does not have argument status.

Would there be a way to run status automatically?

I presume some VBA script could do that open "opctest.exe /cust customer /node node_name" and then once ready could just run "status"

Thanks and appreciate your help

Comment: It is not clear what you are trying to do, what you have tried so far, and what you need help with. Why are you even using VBA for this?

Answer (score 0):

figured it out

echo status | opctest ...

works and produce status of opctest